# Requirejs and coffeescript - how to create a module that has access to a class and its subclasses?

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs

I'm migrating some code at the moment and the previous developer had created a huge javascript file with several classes defined within it. I am trying to split these out into seperate files. Let's say I have the following class:

```
define[], ->
  class Row
    ...
```

and a subclass

```
define["Row"], (Row) ->
  class SpecialisedRow extends Row
    ...
```

I need a "factory" class along these lines:

```
define ["Row", "SpecialisedRow"], (Row, SpecialisedRow) ->

   class RowFactory
     @create: (foo) ->
       if foo
         return new Row()
       else
         return new SpecialisedRow()
```

Allowing me to write code like this;

```
row = RowFactory.create(true)
row = RowFactory.create(false)
```

What I am finding is that this works fine for Row, but in the factory "SpecialisedRow" is null. I've been looking at this for quite a while, have tried all common explanations (typos etc.) - Does anyone know what might be happening here?

EDIT:

It works fine if I don't inherit from Row. So if Specialised row is just:

```
define [] ->
  class SpecialisedRow
    ...
```

Then it's fine. But I need it to inherit from row! Could there be a circular dependency or something going on here?

Comment: `SpecialisedRuleRow` vs `SpecialisedRow`. Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I've edited the post. It's pseudocode really, wasn't a direct copy/paste. So, it was a typo in the ticket!

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to see, if the correct file got loaded?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely getting the right file. I just did an edit above, if I remove the inheritance it works fine (albeit, without the inheritance that I need!)

Comment: My best guess would be some error within the defintion of `SpecialisedRow`. Does it work, if you include just `SpecialisedRow` (but not `Row`) in the main file with having the inheritance?

Comment: Found it. There was a rogue "return" at the bottom of my coffeescript file, so the module was exporting "null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was due to a rogue "return" that was out of place at the very bottom of the SpecialRow class. This caused the module to export null.